# Adding a Native iOS Library to a MAUI Project

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, native, maui, clang++

I develop an app with MAUI (only for iOS), and need to use a library which was written with Xamarin.iOS and it has a static native library  (a file)

I could not use the xamarin project, so I just created a new maui class library project and move the code to this project and added a file as a native library

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ObjcBindingNativeLibrary Include="libAreteUart\a" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And then I added this class library to my maui app project and when I try to build it, I get the following errors

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.2.1007/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(3,3): 
Error: clang++ exited with code 1:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ComboBarcodeApi", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in registrar.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ComboNFCApi", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in registrar.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ComboRFIDApi", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in registrar.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CommonDevice", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in registrar.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CommonReaderInfo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in registrar.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RcpApi", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in registrar.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SDeviceApi", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in registrar.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) (TestMauiApp)
```

As I understand, there is an issue with the Register attribute. Here is my example class

PS: by the way I tried, don't link, only SDK and link all options but got the same error

```
// Token: 0x02000003 RID: 3
    [Register("ComboBarcodeApi", true)]
    public class ComboBarcodeApi : SDeviceApi
    {
        // Token: 0x17000001 RID: 1
        // (get) Token: 0x06000059 RID: 89 RVA: 0x0000206E File Offset: 0x0000026E
        public override NativeHandle ClassHandle
        {
            get
            {
                return ComboBarcodeApi.class_ptr;
            }
        }

        // Token: 0x0600005A RID: 90 RVA: 0x00002078 File Offset: 0x00000278
        [CompilerGenerated]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        [Export("init")]
        public ComboBarcodeApi() : base(NSObjectFlag.Empty)
        {
            base.IsDirectBinding = (base.GetType().Assembly == Messaging.this_assembly);
            if (base.IsDirectBinding)
            {
                base.InitializeHandle(Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend(base.Handle, Selector.GetHandle("init")), "init");
                return;
            }
            base.InitializeHandle(Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper(base.SuperHandle, Selector.GetHandle("init")), "init");
        }
     .....
}
```

I found a similar issue here but no answer or workaround

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17196

Comment: You might have to create the native library anew with Maui

Comment: You mean the a file? It is not my library but Is it not possible to use it with maui?

Comment: and If not, I can find the source code because it is open source. But then what should I do different?  https://asreader.com/products/asr-023xd/ the sources codes are in the "Information for developers" section. And I see that there is obj-c sdk

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I just fixed it yesterday. Maybe this could work for you. Individually go to each file which you see in the error log. And below,

- This issue is due to the old Annotations. The annotation which was working in Xamarin isn't actually working in MAUI.
- In my case,
  In Xamarin it was,

```
    // @protocol TestViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
    [Protocol, Model(AutoGeneratedName = true)]
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    interface TestViewControllerDelegate
```

- Fix in MAUI,

```
    // @protocol TestViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
    [Protocol, Model]
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    interface TestViewControllerDelegate
```

- So, I suggest you refer to each and every file mentioned in your error above to check the annotations which are supported in MAUI.

The sad part is the binding library doesn't show errors individually in every file. Which also means no code autosuggestions. So just follow what is printed in the error window. Kind of Trail and error part as well.
Good Luck!